# ¿Cómo convertir la posición de un vector en un solo vector?

Tags: javascript

Lo que pasa es que tengo la siguiente posición de un vector `filas[0] = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]` el cual me almacena ciertos datos: lo que quiero hacer es crear un vector nuevo con los datos que posee la posición `0` del vector `filas` de tal manera que, por ejemplo, me quede un vector `nuevo = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]`, de forma que pudiera hacer, por ejemplo, `console.log(nuevo[0]);` y tener como salida `"1"`, y así mismo con los demás datos del vector `nuevo`.
Estuve pensando en hacerlo con algún ciclo `for` o `while`, pero no encuentro la manera de hacerlo ya que `fila` es de posición `0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

podes usar la [desestructuracion](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Destructuring_assignment)

```js
var filas = [];
filas[0] = ["1", "2", "3", "4"];
 

const [nuevo] = filas
console.log(nuevo[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Has probado a hacer lo que comentas?

```js
var filas = [];
filas[0] = ["1", "2", "3", "4"];
filas[1] = ["5", "6", "7", "8"];
filas[2] = ["9", "10", "11", "12"];

var num = filas[0];

console.log(num);
console.log(num[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Para hacer una copia del arreglo `filas` an un `nuevo` arreglo puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```javascript
const nuevo = filas.slice();

// o ES6
const nuevo = [...filas];
```